# How to know which hardwares are unidentified or identified but no driver found?

Tags: linux

I have never had to manually install driver for a hardware - thanks to Linux's excellent hardware support.

However, I am expecting that one day I will encounter a Linux workstation with some odd hardwares. Assumes that Linux boots just fine - what indications does Linux give me when:

- Linux does not know what a hardware is
- Linux knows what the hardware is, but cannot find a driver

Comment: Are you looking to do this from a GUI?  Command line?  Any particular distro?

Comment: I am looking for a universal approach, vanilla kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hardware without a driver should be listed in the `dmesg`.

This might not be visible if you use a splash screen at boot, in which case you manually want to peruse it with `dmesg` or `less /var/log/dmesg`. Look for 'no driver attached'.

Comment: Also, `lspci -v` can be used for PCI devices, showing what drivers and modules are being used for particular devices

Comment: True. And not just for PCI devices. PCI-e might not share a technical  background with PCI-e, but it will also be listed.